# Page breaking problem with memoir and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, page-breaking, memoir, incompatibility

When using the `hyperref` package along with `memoir` and the `article` option, the last line of a chapter gets pulled to the next page with the start of the next chapter, like this:

[image: memoir]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper, article]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Whatever}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \chapter{Whatever}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

If you remove `hyperref` that line goes back to its place at the bottom of the first page.

I know `memoir` has problems with `hyperref`, but I still want to use both packages and this is the only problem I encountered so far, so I was hoping there's a way to work around it.

I can, of course, add a `\clearpage` before the affected chapters, but that's not a very nice solution, and I have to wait until my text is done until I can figure out where the page breaks are needed.

(I *do not* want every chapter to start on a new page, hence the `article` option. I just don't want them to pull the previous line when they happen to start on a new page.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Add the instruction `\widowpenalty10000` if you want to suppress all (typographic!) widows.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, but that will just bring yet another line to the second page and leave an even bigger unnecessary gap at the bottom of the first, so I'd still prefer to add a `\clearpage` before the chapter then. Also I don't necessarily want to suppress *all* widows (I already had `widowpenalty` at `9999`), but these have no reason to exist at all, they're just a bug.

Comment: Exactly which problems does memoir have with hyperref?

Comment: @daleif Well, the manual says this in the introduction: "most packages work with the memoir class, the main exception being the hyperref package." And then is goes on to describe a workaround (calling `\usepackage{memhfixc}` after `hyperref`, which still doesn't fix my problem) and it mentions a few random issues throughout other sections. That's pretty much all I know.

Comment: `memhfixc` is automatically loaded after `hyperref`, no need to do ity automatically. It is needed to resurrect some `memoir` features that `hyperref` overwrites.

Comment: I have no idea why it is doing this when `hyperref` is loaded. There is nothing in `memhfixc` that is related to how chapters are formatted. When the `article` option is active, a `\chapter` starts with `\par\@nameuse{chapterblock}` which seems to be the problem. Might be that `hyperref` is inserting anchors into the `\chapter` command and these get messed up with the `\par`. I tried `\newcommand\chapterblock{\vskip0pt}` which seems to work

Comment: @daleif Awesome, `\newcommand\chapterblock{\vskip0pt}` seems to work perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just repeating my comment as an answer. If anyone can explain **why** it happens I'd like to know.

I have no idea why it is doing this when `hyperref` is loaded. There is nothing in `memhfixc` that is related to how chapters are formatted. When the article option is active, a `\chapter` starts with `\par\@nameuse{chapterblock}` (`\chapterblock` is undefined by default) which seems to be the problem. Might be that `hyperref` is inserting anchors into the `\chapter` command and these get messed up with the `\par`. I tried

```
\newcommand\chapterblock{\vskip0pt}
```

which seems to work